# Comparing character array contatinig hexa values

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am receining NSData in following way

```
 - (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
    { 
    char *ptr = (void *)[data bytes]; // set a pointer to the beginning of your data   bytes
```

I am receiving the data then I need to compare this data with following array

```
        char ch[3]={0x04,0x01,0X00};
```

becuase that data is coming from server, but data is dynamic i need to compare many such arrays with server data i found following method but it is static method but can no compare all arrays in following way

```
     if(*ptr == 0x04) {
       }
      ptr++;
      if(*ptr == 0x01) {
       }
  ptr++;
  if(*ptr==0X00){
       }
but i can not compare all array so please help how
```

i can compare

```
              char *ptr = (void *)[data bytes];
```

with

```
               char ch[3]={0x04,0x01,0X00};
```

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an `NSData` object for the data you are comparing (`ch[3]`), then you can use [`-[NSData rangeOfData:options:range:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-SW7) to find the pattern.

Here is an example

```
//This is just mock up data to represent what would be passed into your method
unsigned char ch1[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x04, 0x01, 0x00, 0x0F }; 
NSData *data1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:ch1 
                                       length:sizeof(ch1)];
//This is the data used for the comparison
NSData *data2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:(unsigned char[]){0x04, 0x01, 0x00} 
                                       length:3];

NSRange range = [data1 rangeOfData:data2 
                           options:0 
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [data1 length])];

if(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
     NSLog(@"Found pattern!");
}
```

Comment: This works if you have multiple `NSData` objects in an `NSArray`. Just loop over them and check the ranges to see if any match.

Comment: also can you help me please how can see that data which data ic coming from server, as server is a device and some times it sends strange packets , so how can view that data by NSLog and UIAlert,please help

Comment: You can `NSLog` an `NSData` object using `%@`. `NSLog(@"%@", data);`.

Comment: i want to add server commands in database as a string , can u please help me how can i convert this into NSString

Comment: [`-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData:encoding:)